# Using AKBooster with AKAmplitudeTracker in Audiokit

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

My question here is about adding an `AKBooster` to `AKAmplitudeTracker` before it gets added to the output later in the signal chain. It should look something like this:

```
do {
   try sprite.MIDISamplerPlayer.loadAudioFile(myAudioFile)
} catch let error as NSError {
   print("There's an error: \(error)")
}

sprite.amplitudeTracker = AKAmplitudeTracker(sprite.MIDISamplerPlayer)
sprite.silentBooster = AKBooster(sprite.amplitudeTracker)

sprite.silentBooster?.gain = 0

sprite.silentBooster! >>> mixer
sprite.MIDISamplerPlayer.enableMIDI(sprite.samplerMIDI.client, name: "My MIDISampler")
sprite.MIDISamplerPlayer >>> mixer

sequencer = AKSequencer(filename: myMIDI)

AudioKit.output = mixer
AudioKit.start()

sequencer!.play()
```

The issue I'm having is that the gain is reporting as 0.0 but volume is playing as normal, ie the gain has no effect on the output.

I can't have `AKBooster` added to signal chain at the end as I want the `AKBooster` to be added to tracks in the sequencer.

Ideas on how to solve this much appreciated! Thanks 8•)

**EDITED**
missed some steps in my process, noticed after Aure's answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Aure again (as his suggestion solved the issue). Amended code as follows, and now working as expected.

```
sprite.amplitudeTracker = AKAmplitudeTracker(sprite.MIDISamplerPlayer)
sprite.MIDISamplerPlayer.enableMIDI(sprite.samplerMIDI.client, name: "My MIDISampler")
sprite.silentBooster = AKBooster(sprite.amplitudeTracker)

sprite.silentBooster?.gain = 0
sprite.silentBooster! >>> mixer

//sprite.MIDISamplerPlayer >>> mixer
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're not putting the booster in the chain.  You'd have to do

```
sprite.silentBooster >>> mixer
```

instead of sprite.MIDIsampler or else neither the tracker nor the booster will have audio pulled through it.

Comment: Hi Aure, and thanks. I realised I missed some steps in my process (added above now in edit)... which means that the issue is different?